# Is it possible to use HTML in a Shiny downloadHandler generated report

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I am beginning to use CSS together with my R Markdowns to use a consistent defined look to all my reports. So far I have been using a css.styles document and using the occasional bit of HTML in my markdown to create things like boxes for text.
I am now trying to bring the same consistent look to HTML markdowns I create using downloadHandler in my Shiny app. When I add the HTML code to my markdown it seems to be ignored in the generated report.

I use a Linux server for RStudio Server (that the Shiny app is run from) and also a Windows desktop version of RStudio. My regular R Markdowns work in both instances.

Below is the regular HTML I have in Markdown (below my YAML header) that is not working when passed through Shiny and downloadHandler.

```html
<div id="box">
`r params$identifier`
</div>
```

The R code works and this appears in the downloadHandler generated report, just without any of the CSS defined styles applied to it. Other CSS commands are applied to non-custom elements.

Comment: I don't think shiny works in this way,HTML tempalte is totally different from Markdown. Read https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/templates.html for how to use HTML templates. Also, you need to use `downloadHandler`

Comment: @YifuYan, I am using `downloadHandler` to make my reports, as I state above. For this you essentially write an R Markdown, its in this markdown that my HTML is not being recognised.

Comment: I don't think Rshiny recognizes Markdown Syntax in HTML templates. You need to use something like `{{params$identifier}}` in your HTML instead of `\`r params$identifier\``. Please read the link in previous comment, it should answer your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested it turns out how I had the html above was written fine.

The problem came from the fact that i had `runtime: shiny` in the YAML header of my markdown report. Now I've taken that out, everything works fine.